# How determine the type of device based on hostname, ip, operating system ...?

Tags: linux, windows, system-info

I'm working on integrating some scanners into one of our solutions, I need to be able to tell if a device is:

- a desktop computer (in a sens of computer used with os offering some gui)
- a server used as infrastructure
- a mobile device
- an IOT device

The information I can get resembles this:

```
os name: winX
vendor: nutanix
os type: windows
services: kerberos port 88 protocol tcp
hostname: mycomputerdummy
fqdn: somevalue
ipv4: ipv4 address
```

Is there any known algorithm / intuition of determining the device type based on this information ? Thank you

Comment: Could you extend your question with some information about the setup and scope. For any kind of security this would fall flat. If it's just for statistics it would allow for ... uncleaner and less strict solutions.

Comment: Run the scanner, match your findings to the known types of devices, and build this into the scanner.

Comment: As Harrymc says, there is no magic way to identify all devices. the folks who have worked on code for system fingerprinting (like in nmap for instance) have spent a lot of time and effort on it, and they still can't always determine what the device is, especially for IoT devices.

Comment: @harrymc could you please extend on this solution ?

Comment: @PatrickAbraham the aim is merely statistical, I have a number of assets and I need to categorize them

Answer (score 2):

There exists no planetary catalog permitting to identify all the
devices in the world. You would need to build your own catalog.

The data you have indicated you can get from your devices is
already very good. Once your scanner is functional, run it on
your network and try to identify the devices. In case of
a device that is difficult to identify, try to have as many other
devices turned off as you can.

Once you have methods for identifying the devices, build them
into your scanner, so you can easily and quickly understand
the state of the network.

Answer (score 1):

First run an scan focused on OS name. This will give some broad sets.

Just catalog all of them by OS once to get a broad understanding of the quality of your database. Is there a bunch of diversity? Then you should already see some patterns. Windows server will most likely use Windows Server OS. Desktop machines will most likely use either Windows/MacOS or Linux.

If your database is very homogeneous I would start to check if the scanner really can determine the OS. Unless there is some policy that everyone has to use Windows for everything.

What I want to say never trust a black-box. Always check your data. Does it align with your what you witness? If not check the source.

Then just start to build subsets from there.